# Partial build of Qt6 from source

Tags: c++, qt, qt6

I need to install Qt6 on Ubuntu 18. Since qt6 is not in the repositories (or is it?), I have to compile them from the source code. However, I do this on my VDS server, which is not very powerful (2 cores, 4GB of RAM), so I do not have enough power for standard Qt6 compilation (compilation crashes with errors like "I do not have enough RAM"). I wondered if it was possible to compile only the modules I needed for QtHttpServer (an extension for Qt6).
I tried to find this information in the documentation, but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The old Qt5 way is to pass `-skip` to the configure command line.  e.g. `configure .... -skip qtremoteobjects -skip qtwebengine`  According to the [Qt6 build documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/configure-options.html), this option still exists. (Scroll near the bottom of that page on "Excluding Qt Modules"). In your case, you will probably be passing a lot of `-skip` statements when you run configure.  Each available skip option is a top level directory in the source tree.

I haven't investigated building with Qt 6 yet, like I have with Qt 5. But the other easy way on Qt5 to not build stuff you don't need is to simply delete any top level directory from the source tree.  For example, if you didn't want to build `qtremoteobjects` or `qtwebengine`, you just delete those top level directories. (We always delete qtwebengine from the source tree every time we take a new drop - it's essentially all of Chromium and is larger than the rest of the code base combined!)  No idea if deleting directories work on Qt6 with their new Ninja/CMake environment.

Comment: There's a `-make <part>` option that claims to only build what you specify. But I can't find any information on what a "part" is, I haven't been able to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to install Qt6 on Ubuntu 18. Since qt6 is not in the repositories (or is it?), I have to compile them from the source code.

That doesn't entirely track — Qt makes [binary downloads](https://www.qt.io/download/) available via their online installer, you should be able to download and install Qt6 that way. I have a copy of Qt 6.1.0 installed in `$HOME/Qt/` on my Fedora 33 box, completely separate from the system install of Qt 5.15.2 in `/usr/lib64/qt5/`. And I didn't compile any of it.

However, perhaps you need to compile other code against the Qt sources — getting a working build environment is still worthwhile.

#### Configuring the build

Running `./configure --help` in the source tree lists the options available for configuration, including giving the definition of a `<part>`:

```
$ ./configure --help
# ...snip...
Component selection:

  -skip  ......... Exclude an entire repository from the build.
  -make  ......... Add  to the list of parts to be built.
                         Specifying this option clears the default list first.
                         (allowed values: libs, tools, examples, tests,
                         benchmarks, manual-tests, minimal-static-tests)
                         [default: libs and examples, also tools if not
                         cross-building, also tests if -developer-build]
  -nomake  ....... Exclude  from the list of parts to be built.
```

So, `-make` is too high-level to be of any use to you.

#### Building targets

That's OK, though, because now that Qt is using CMake to generate its build system, you actually have fairly fine-grained control over the process. After generating the build tree, you can specify precisely which [CMake targets](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#binary-targets) you want to build, instead of the default `all`, by adding a `--target <name>` argument to the `cmake --build` command line. Running `cmake --build <builddir> --target help` will get the build tool to list its known targets (at least with `make` or `ninja`, not sure if that's universal).

`QtHttpServer` itself isn't listed as a target. There is an `http` *feature* listed which is part of the `Qt::Network` target, but you can't build features. Presumably `QtHttpServer` is also part of `Qt::Network`, though — which you can build in isolation <s>(but with all required dependencies)</s><sup>*</sup> using the target `Network`.

* – (As it turns out, CMake will configure the build to compile any *runtime* dependencies of `QtNetwork` automatically, but there are dependencies at install time that Qt haven't fully defined as prerequisites for the targets that require them.)

#### Round 1

So, after downloading the Qt6 sources to `$HOME/Qt/6.1.0/Src` using their online installer, my initial attempt went:

```sh
cd $HOME/Qt/6.1.0/Src
./configure -prefix $HOME/Qt/my_6.1.0
cmake --build . --target Network
cmake --install .  # Installs to the location given in `configure -prefix`
```

...That failed at the `--install` step, because it was missing helper tools used by the install process.

#### Round 2

So I did another build run:

```sh
cmake --build . --target qttools
```

That actually takes much longer, because to build the full set of tools (some graphical) I now need to have most of `QtCore`, `QtGui`, and `QtWidgets` built as dependencies, along with big chunks of `QtDeclarative` (where `QML` and `QtQuick` live) and other modules, all of which I skipped in the first run because I only wanted `QtNetwork`.

Excluding some of the tree with `./configure` options initially would've helped here, as I could've avoided building a lot of tools I *don't* need. There might also be more fine-grained targets available that would let me build just the specific tools needed by the install scripts (with fewer dependencies), but meh. Qt's pretty useless without the core libraries anyway. Still, if you're as constrained as you say, taking some more time with the initial `configure` to pare down the build set, as selbie detailed in the other answer, is still worthwhile.

#### An aside: installing with CMake

It's worth noting that `cmake --install` *won't* trigger additional builds (hence my first attempt failing); it only installs whatever's already been built. So, it's safe to run an experimental `cmake --install .` at any point in the process. Worst case, components are missing.

(In stark contrast to tools like `make`, where you can usually run a `make install` to build *and* install a tree all in one step, if you run `cmake --install` on a completely un-built tree it won't trigger any builds. In a normal CMake tree it will just start spewing failure messages about every one of the default outputs being missing, then exit "successfully" having done nothing. However, Qt have some custom install scripts that expect to access certain files in the build tree, so doing the same thing in an unbuilt/partially-built Qt build tree causes the install scripts to error out when it can't find those files.)

#### Round 3

So, joke was on me: Even after building all of `qttools`, `cmake --install .` *still* failed with the EXACT SAME error message:

```
CMake Error at qtbase/src/tools/tracegen/cmake_install.cmake:53 (file):
  file INSTALL cannot find "$HOME/Qt/6.1.0/Src/qtbase/libexec/tracegen":
  No such file or directory.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  qtbase/src/cmake_install.cmake:67 (include)
  qtbase/cmake_install.cmake:231 (include)
  cmake_install.cmake:47 (include)
```

Seems `tracegen` isn't even part of `qttools`... but it **IS** a target of its own. So what I should've done in Round 2, instead, is:

```sh
cmake --build . --target tracegen
```

After doing that, this works to install (only) `QtNetwork`:

```
cmake --install ./qtbase/src/network
```

I can also do things like:

```
cmake --build . --target qtbase
cmake --build . --target qmake  # The qtbase install crashes without it
cmake --install ./qtbase
```

To install individual high-level modules. QtBase is by far the most critical, without it you don't really have a Qt installation by any reasonable definition.

After doing that, this is a good test of whether the basics are working:

```sh
cmake --build . --target qtdiag
cmake --install ./qttools/src/qtdiag
$HOME/Qt/my_6.1.0/bin/qtdiag
```

...If all is well (and it is), copious information about the state of the components I've installed so far should be dumped to stdout.